# Операция «Перекрытие» — с большой буквы?

Tags: ономастика, прописная-строчная

*Операция «Перекрытие».*
С большой буквы пишется название операции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это имя собственное, название мероприятия, пишется с прописной буквы.

Пример: С 14 января на территории БМР проходит крупномасштабное профилактическое мероприятие **«Перекрытие»,** основная цель которого — выявление грубых нарушений ПДД.

Сравнить: Началась партизанская операция «Рельсовая война».